# Connect a class to the main class

Tags: java, r

I am very new to java, I have one class ConnectR.java and it has main method, also I have MainApp class which  is the main application. so I want to know If I want to click a button in the MAinApp how can I implement the ConnerR.java Class.
thank you very mcuh

Comment: Thank you. I just change the name of my main method in ConnectR.java to connect() and call ConnectR.connect(); Finally it works.

Answer (score 1):

`main` is a special method but still a method. So it can be called like any other method:

```
    //Call ConnectR main method
    ConnectR.main(stringarrayinput);
```